# PHP: Problems with numbers/type casting

Tags: php, operators

I have two values:

`$currentValue` will always have two decimal places (can be .00).

`$usersValue` can either be an integer, or a decimal to two decimal places.

The issue I have is that these are both strings (example):

```
var_dump($currentValue) = string(6) "100.50"
var_dump($usersValue) = string(5) "52.50" || string(2) "52"
```

Now I need to do some logic on these:

```
if($usersValue > $currentValue) // Is users value greater than the current value
if($usersValue < $currentValue) // Is users value less than the current value
if($usersValue == $currentValue) // Is the users value equal to the current value
```

In my mind, I think the two variables should always be declared as floats, since the `$currentValue` will always be a float, then you can do the maths...?

So my questions:

1. How do I properly convert a string into a float? For example: If my `$currentValue = string(8) "2,061.14"`, and I do `$newCurrentValue = (float)$currentValue`, `$newCurrentValue = string(1) "2"`.  No idea whats going on there?
2. If the `$usersValue = string(2) "52"`, how do I convert this so `$usersValue = float(52.00)`?
3. If all variables are floats, am I able to do the logic I need as described above? From my testing, I found the `<` and `>` operators worked, but not `==`...?

Really confused here, thanks.

Comment: If a string contains thousands separators like `2,061.14` then you need to remove those before anything else (using something like `$value = str_replace(',','',$value);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a string to float, use the [`floatval()`](http://php.net/floatval) function.

For `$usersValue`, you can use the function directly:

```
$usersValue = floatval($usersValue);
```

But this isn't possible with `$currentValue`.  You will need to strip off the commas first:

```
$currentValue = str_replace(',', '', $currentValue);
$currentValue = floatval($currentValue);
```

Now, since both the numbers are of the same type, your comparisons should work:

```
echo ($usersValue > $currentValue) ? '$usersValue greater' : '$currentValue greater';
echo ($usersValue < $currentValue) ? '$currentValue greater' : '$usersValue greater';
echo ($usersValue == $currentValue) ? 'equal' : 'not equal';
```

Output:

```
$currentValue greater
$currentValue greater
not equal
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this:

```
$currentValue = (float)$currentValue;
$usersValue = (float)$usersValue;
```

Your problem is that you have a "," in your value, a float can only contain numbers and ONE dot